# Using ansible, how would I delete all items except for a specified set in a directory?

Tags: ansible

I can, of course, use a shell command, but I was hoping there was an ansible way to do this, so that I can get the "changed/unchanged" response.

Comment: Hmmmm it does appear as if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385507/ansible-delete-unmanaged-files-from-directory might work.

Answer (score 16):

Here's how I do it:

```
- name: Capture files to delete
  find:
    paths: /path/to/directory
    file_type: file
    excludes: 
      - "myfirst.file"
      - "mysecond.file"
  register: found_files

- name: Delete files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ found_files['files'] }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [what you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385507/ansible-delete-unmanaged-files-from-directory) per your comment, if you end up needing to do a shell command, you can use the `command` module with `removes` parameter ([doc](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html)).  It will skip the step if the file already (doesn't) exist, which will prevent it from reporting a `changed` on the step.  You'll still need to iterate over a list like in the other answer, however.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this exactly what I was looking for!

One useful addition I want to share: for trimming the output to only the filenames add `loop_control` to your cleanup task:

```
- name: Delete files
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ found_files['files'] }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```