# Ansible task wont delete selected files, marks as OK and does nothing

Tags: ansible

so I tried getting this solution to work [Ansible: Delete unmanaged files from directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385507/ansible-delete-unmanaged-files-from-directory).

I managed to get the list working and everything it even detect the file it needs to delete, but it doesn't delete it, in log it just says `OK` and nothing happens?

Here is my task shortened

```yaml
- shell: ls -1 /usr/local/ansible/roles/common/templates/etc/named/zones/
  register: managed_files
  become: true

- shell: ls -1 /etc/named/zones/
  register: zonesdel  
  become: true

- name: Debug unmanaged files
  debug:
    var: item
  with_items: "{{ zonesdel.stdout_lines }}"
  when: item not in managed_files.stdout_lines

- name: Remove unmanaged files on remote server
  file: 
    path: /etc/named/zones/{{ item }}
    state: absent
  with_items: zonesdel.stdout_lines
  when: item not in managed_files
  become: true
```

and in theory it should work, it should make sure those files are absent.

But it doesn't, in log file the debug portions skips the files that are in both locations and it it says `OK` to those which are absent in Ansible repository.

```yaml
TASK [netsrv : Debug unmanaged files] ********************
skipping: [netsrv-1.joj.sk] => (item=10.in-addr.arpa.conf) 
skipping: [netsrv-1.joj.sk] => (item=office.conf) 
skipping: [netsrv-1.joj.sk] => (item=7.conf) 
ok: [netsrv-1.joj.sk] => (item=aaaaa_test.conf) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "aaaaa_test.conf"
}
skipping: [netsrv-1.joj.sk] => (item=akoto.conf) 
skipping: [netsrv-1.joj.sk] => (item=media.conf)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
  with_items: zonesdel.stdout_lines
  when: item not in managed_files
```

> *and in theory it should work, it should make sure those files are absent.*

It looks like you want to compare the elements of two lists, so I do not think so.

---

In order to get a list of files from a directory it is recommended to use the dedicated Ansible Module for (and as in any case). Here [`find` module – Return a list of files based on specific criteria](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html). Especially for the given Use Case because of [Why **not** parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

```yaml
- name: Get list of managed zone files
  find:
    path: /usr/local/ansible/roles/common/templates/etc/named/zones/
  register: managed_files
```

It will generate a list of files found. To filter the filepath out one may use

```yaml
managed_files.files | map(attribute='path') | list
```

or to get the filename ([`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/basename_filter.html)) only

```yaml
managed_files.files | map(attribute='path') | list | map('basename')
```

Generated lists can be then compared by the [`difference` filter – the difference of one list from another](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html). The resulting difference list can be used for the next task, in the Use Case here, removing the files.

---

A minimal example playbook for testing ...

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get list of managed zone files
    find:
      path: managed
    register: managed

  - set_fact:
      MANAGED: "{{ managed.files | map(attribute='path') | list | map('basename') }}"

  - name: Get list of installed zone files
    find:
      path: zones
    register: zones

  - set_fact:
      ZONES: "{{ zones.files | map(attribute='path') | list | map('basename') }}"

  - name: Show the difference, unmanaged zones
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ZONES | difference(MANAGED) }}"

  - name: Remove unmanaged files
    file: 
      path: zones/{{ item }}
      state: absent
    loop: "{{ ZONES | difference(MANAGED) }}"
```